# PHP str_replace with only data from middle

Tags: php, str-replace

I have a block of XML in a variable that looks something like this:

```
<DailySchedule ID="1363108332926" Name="Daily Backup" Hour="11" Minute="0" Duration="-1"     BackupType="FILE" LastUpdated="1363108332926" Interval="-1" EnableSkipBackup="N"/><DailySchedule ID="1363699291763" Name="Schedule3" Hour="21" Minute="0" Duration="-1" BackupType="FILE" LastUpdated="1363699291763" Interval="-1" EnableSkipBackup="N"/><WeeklySchedule ID="1363697754949" Name="Schedule0" Sun="N" Mon="Y" Tue="Y" Wed="N" Thu="N" Fri="N" Sat="N" Hour="21" Minute="0" Duration="-1" BackupType="FILE" LastUpdated="1363697754949" Interval="-1" EnableSkipBackup="N"/><MonthSchedule ID="1363698082481" Name="Schedule1" Occurrence="Last" Criteria="Weekday" Date="0" Hour="21" Minute="0" Duration="-1" BackupType="FILE" LastUpdated="1363698082481" EnableSkipBackup="N"/>
```

Based on the ID of a schedule, I need to remove the entire XML block from the string.  For example, if I had the ID of 1363697754949, I would need to remove `<WeeklySchedule ID="1363697754949" Name="Schedule0" Sun="N" Mon="Y" Tue="Y" Wed="N" Thu="N" Fri="N" Sat="N" Hour="21" Minute="0" Duration="-1" BackupType="FILE" LastUpdated="1363697754949" Interval="-1" EnableSkipBackup="N"/>`

I have tried `str_replace('1363697754949', '', $xmlString);` but that only removes the actual numbers.  I need to remove the entire XML tag.  Is there some sort of wildcard or other pattern I can use to accomplish this?  Thank you!

Comment: Google `DOMDocument`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best solution would be build a valid XML document and using a proper library to manipulate it.
A faster solution could be use `preg_replace()`, like this:

```
preg_replace('/<([^>]+)ID="1363697754949"([^>]+)>/', '', $yourString);
```